# Making the Subtitle in a Table View a time stamp (Objective C)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uialertview, ios7

I am working on an educational task manager and I am wanting to add a Time stamp to the subtitle section of the cell. I have coded the title of the task correctly but I want to replace subtitle with a time stamp of when the task was created.

[image]

I would like to turn where it says Subtitle into a time stamp

Could somebody please help me? Just comment below with the code that I need to add to the Controllers attached to this TableView. Below is my ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource>

-(IBAction)add:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *tasksArray;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITableView *tasksTable;

@end
```

and this is my ViewController.m

```
@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize tasksArray = _tasksArray;
@synthesize tasksTable = _tasksTable;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    NSLog(@"Test");
    self.tasksArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(IBAction)add:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender
{
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Enter the task name"          message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Add", nil];
alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
[alert show];
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    NSString *buttonTile = [alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];
    if ([buttonTile isEqualToString:@"Add"]) {
        [self.tasksArray addObject:[alertView textFieldAtIndex:0].text];
        [self.tasksTable reloadData];
    }
}

#pragma mark
#pragma table view

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return self.tasksArray.count;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault     reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = [self.tasksArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}

@end
```

I am new to StackOverFlow, so don't judge my post if it sucks :p haha! Cheers and please help me!

Comment: What should the timestamp be? Is it when the cell was created, or are you supplying the time in the taskArray?

Comment: When the new task was created.

Comment: This is off topic, but your UI looks nice and clean :)

Comment: You could just run through the introductory tutorials on the developer site. They deal with rabies views and persistence. It's better to get some Cadiz understanding rather than throwing code at a compiler.

Answer (score 2):

To create your data array:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    NSString *buttonTile = [alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];
    if ([buttonTile isEqualToString:@"Add"]) {    
        NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

        [dictionary setObject:[alertView textFieldAtIndex:0].text forKey:@"text"];
        [dictionary setObject:[NSDate date] forKey:@"date"];

        [self.taskArray addObject:dictionary];

        [self.tasksTable reloadData];
    }
}
```

In your cellForRow

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault     reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    NSDictionary *currentDictionary = [self.taskArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [currentDictionary objectForKey:@"text"];

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"];

    NSString *dateString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:[currentDictionary objectForKey:@"date"]];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = dateString;

    return cell;
}
```

You can see the date formatter values [here](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-19.html#Date_Format_Patterns)

Comment: Okay I've added it but the cell.detailTextLabel = datestring; comes back with the warning/error; assignment to readonly property. Do I need to add something to the .h?

Comment: I edited my post to give you more. I also fixed the error you were talking about. I forgot the ".text" property

Comment: Thank you for the help, could you please look at my next problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17076385/uitableview-cells-delete-after-going-to-a-different-page